# is there an json simple function to get all the keys from a jsonobject?

Tags: java, json-simple

I'm trying for the first time to use the jsonsimple library on java.
So i formatted a  json object using a String.
the Object is the following

```
{
   "mario":{
   "city": "rome",
   "birth": 1980,
  "haircolor": "blonde"
  },
"Lucas": {
  "city": "milan",
  "birth": 1985,
  "haircolor": "brown"
   }
}
```

From these object i need to get the names in a String format.
Thanks everyone for any kinda of help.

Comment: `JSONObject` implements `java.util.Map` so you can simply call `myJsonObject.keySet()`

Comment: @codeflush.dev - would your comment above be better as an answer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

[JsonObject](https://jar-download.com/javaDoc/com.github.cliftonlabs/json-simple/2.3.0/org/json/simple/JsonObject.html) implements [java.util.Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), so you can simply call the [`keySet`-Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) on your JsonObject.

Example:

```
JsonObject myJsonObject = ...;
Set<String> allNamesInThisObject = myJsonObject.keySet();
```

Comment: using that i got that set can't be casted.. But unfortunally i don't know what else  do

Comment: Why do you want to cast the Set?